# Is a gap between walls and floor due to settling?

Tags: walls, floor, foundation, gap

There is an addition to the back of the house we recently purchased (5 months ago). We have noticed gaps appearing between the old back ending of the house and the walls of the addition. Then we noticed some horizontal separation between the floor of the addition and the wall of the addition. Is this settling or should we be concerned?

The image shows the old wall to the right (exposed brick) and the new wall to the left and the wood-looking flooring.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually the gap is requirement.

It is there to allow the wood to expand and contract

Usually the gap is covered by the base boards.

Comment: Additionally, the gap at the walls should be covered by some sort of cove molding or other trim piece.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like normal expansion and contraction. There doesn't appear from the pics that the structure is dropping. The gap of the "crack" is somewhat uniform.
Usually the cure is to wait for a cold day when the gap may be the largest. Then fill it with polyester caulk like Vulkem. Paint when dry and you are done. As mentioned above, the flooring gap is required and usually covered by a baseboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about settling then measure the gap in a few places, perhaps draw a line on the wall an inch from the brick. Measure that line in 3 months and then again in 6 months. If it's still an inch, then if it ever did settle it's done settling and you can make your cosmetic repairs. If it's more than an inch then it is settling and should be looked at.